# how to get the last value of the array variable in loops

Tags: java, arrays, loops, swap

Here is my code:

```
class test {
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    int a[]={5,8,9,7,3};
    int j;

    for(j=0;j<a.length-1;j++)
    {
        if(a[j]>a[j+1])
        {
            int temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[j+1];
            a[j+1]=temp;
        }
        System.out.print(a[j]+"   "); // last value of array a[4] is not printed
    }
  }
}
```

This is one part of my program, here last value of the array is not printed?!

Can you help me anyone how to get the last value of array?

Comment: The last value is not printed because your for loop goes only to a.length - 2, and your last value is on a.length - 1

Comment: And hint: read about java coding style conventions. Class names start UpperCase; always. And even for learning purposes, a name like "a" says absolutely nothing. Call it "testArray" or something like that.

Comment: tnq...but is there any other logic to print all the array swap values by using any other loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: add another print statement **after** the loop; like:

```
 System.out.println(a[a.length-1]);
```

for example.

for example. The point is that your loop is (correctly skipping that last index). So one reasonable solution is to do that last print statement **after** your loop; as you know that you want to print it.

Comment: you are correct..is there any other logic with the help of loops concept only

Answer (score 2):

> ***...here last value of the array is not printed...***

is not printed because you are doing this:

```
for(j=0;j<a.length-1;j++)
```

to only print the last element is enough to do:

```
System.out.println(a[a.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is not printed is because your `for` loop ranges from `0` (inclusive) to `a.lenth-1` (exclusive). Therefore the loop is *not* executed for the last element.

You can however not simply set the bound one higher because then the swap will crash (generate an out of bounds exception).

You can solve the problem by simply printing the last element **after** the loop:

```
class test
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        int a[]={5,8,9,7,3};
        int j;

        for(j=0;j<a.length-1;j++)
        {
            if(a[j]>a[j+1])
            {
                int temp=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=temp;
            }
            System.out.print(a[j]+"   "); // last value of array a[4] is not printed
        }
        if(a.length > 0) {
            System.out.print(a[a.length-1]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: tnq...is there any other logic to print all the array swap values by using any other loops?